# Python ошибка в int SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

Tags: python, python-3.x

вот код:

```
int(age) = input('Ваш возраст: ')
```

вот ошибка при запуске кода:

```
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

почитайте про функции и как они работают

ваш код должен быть таким:

```
age = int(input('Ваш возраст: '))
```

или таким

```
age_text = input('Ваш возраст: ')
age = int(age_text)
```

Comment: а также про присвоение переменных.